# Maven: Simple classpathLayoutType is generating classpath similar to repository classpathLayoutType

Tags: java, maven, maven-jar-plugin

I have a maven project which does the following:

- Generates the jar and copies it into `target/dist` directory.
- Copies all dependency jars into `target/dist/lib` directory.
- Distributes the `dist` folder.
- Requires the dependency jars to be executed in the classpath when running the jar.

When I added this code in my pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It generated the following classpath in the jar:

```
Class-Path: lib/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.2/gson-2.8.2.jar
```

Obviously, this won't work because the classpath I need is as follows:

```
Class-Path: lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/gson-2.8.2.jar
```

I went to[this page](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html). According the documentation, what I need is the default `classpathLayoutType` of `simple`. But the classpath generated is in a repository layout. I even tried explicitly adding the below tag, but with no success.

```
<classpathLayoutType>simple</classpathLayoutType>
```

Why isn't the `simple` layout type not working?

### **EDIT**

I have achieved what I need using custom layout type as follows:

```
<classpathLayoutType>custom</classpathLayoutType>
<customClasspathLayout>lib/$${artifact.artifactId}-$${artifact.version}$${dashClassifier?}.$${artifact.extension}</customClasspathLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of the maven archiver plugin are you using? Version 3.0.2 has [a bug in ManifestConfiguration.class](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHARED-551):

```
 public String getClasspathLayoutType()
 {
    return "simple".equals(this.classpathLayoutType) ? "repository" : this.classpathLayoutType;
  }
```

The method for the ClasspathLayoutType is returning the wrong type.
In maven archiver version 3.1.1 the bug is fixed, with layout types taking these possible values:

```
  public static final String CLASSPATH_LAYOUT_TYPE_SIMPLE = "simple";
  public static final String CLASSPATH_LAYOUT_TYPE_REPOSITORY = "repository";
  public static final String CLASSPATH_LAYOUT_TYPE_CUSTOM = "custom";
```

Just try a higher fixed version.

Comment: Thank you :) But, I've moved on and I'm working in a complete different field now. So, I can't check if this fixes my problem :) Just a question. It doesn't look like a bug. It looks like a deliberate code. Why would they do like that? Any reason?